# Can the formation of gypsum evaporites (sand roses) be simulated in the lab?

Tags: desert, crystals, evaporation, laboratory

Has the process of formation of sand roses been simulated in laboratory conditions, or does it take too long?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has.

Cody & Cody (1998), Journal of Sedimentary Research.

http://archives.datapages.com/data/sepm/journals/v55-58/data/058/058002/0247.htm

Abstract:

> Gypsum crystals were grown in experimental conditions analogous to
>   saline terrestrial environments within bentonite clay gels by
>   diffusion control at three different temperatures, four brine
>   salinities, and four tannic acid (a model terrestrial humic substance)
>   concentrations. The resulting crystals correspond to natural gypsum
>   formed in terrestrial environments. Prismatic gypsum typically grew at
>   both high and low temperatures in the absence of the organic additive.
>   With increasing organic acid concentrations, the prismatic crystals
>   progressively became flattened perpendicular to [001], and two
>   temperature-dependent trends developed. At low temperatures, a
>   hemi-bipyramidal habit dominated by 1111 faces developed, whereas the
>   lenticular e103 dominated habit forme at higher temperatures. **With
>   progressively greater concentrations of organic material a(100)
>   penetration twinning developed, secondary complex nucleation occurred
>   near the twin interfaces, and finally, rosette and rosette-like
>   aggregates formed.** Higher temperatures generally favored better-formed
>   and larger rosettes. The presence of 5% and 15% NaCl greatly decreased
>   nucleation density and resulted in larger single crystals and crystal
>   aggregates. The a(100) penetation twins appear to be diagnostic of
>   gypsum growth in natural terrestrial sediments at a pH greater than
>   7.5.

Relevant bit about gypsum roses is in **bold**.